# Strange situation regarding connection to SQL Server with JDBC

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I have an application that I have developed 2 years ago that stopped working due to not be able to connect to a remote SQL Server 2008 anymore, and I can't figure it out why this is happening.

This is the situation: I have a desktop where I have jdk1.6.0_31 and I developed a small 'helloworld' like application to test the connection to this remote SQL Server, even with the firewall off I can't make it connect. Still on this desktop I have Visual Studio where I'm able to connect to this SQL Server (so firewall is not the problem I guess).

I have a laptop where I tested this 'helloworld' JDBC app, and on this laptop the application works, and I just copied the app from the desktop to the laptop.

I also copied the app to my virtual server (that hosts the application that I developed 2 years ago) and there this 'helloworld' app does not work also, with firewall on or off, it doesn't matter.

So I'm wondering, what in the world could be leading to such a strange situation? JDBC on desktop does not work, but through visual studio it does, JDBC on laptop works, and JDBC on virtual server does not?? I'm really confused about this. I have been struggling with this for a week already. And that's why I really need your help people!!

Best regards and thanks in advance!
Bruno

Comment: Can you turn on Profiler and see if your SQLServer is getting anything when you try to connect?  Also, maybe there are differences in the protocols that the two are using to connect to SQLServer and somehow one of those protocols got reset on your SQLServer. To check that you could go to SqlServer Configuration Manager and enable all protocols (TCP/IP, Shared Memory, Named Pipes) to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I expect this is as simple as a connection string issue.  The format for a connection string might change for different languages (Java vs C#).  Can you please post the connection string you are using -- rename constants of course -- I just want to see the format you are using.